# Centering jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

Has anyone faced this before - I have a jQuery UI dialog which is being perfectly centered in FF as well as IE but is stuck to the left in Chrome!

The code is pretty standard. Still, I am copying it below:

```
<script>
$(function() {$('#dialog1 ').dialog({autoOpen: false, 
width: 700, height: 400, buttons: {
                        "Ok": function() { 
                            $(this).dialog("close"); 
                            }, 
                        "Cancel": function() { 
                            $(this).dialog("close"); 
                            }
                        }
                    });
        });
</script>

<div id="dialog1">Hello</div>
```

It is opened using `$("dialog1").dialog("open")` when a button is clicked

Comment: I'd be tempted to give styling it specifically in the callback a go. With a `position:absolute;left:50%;margin-left:-350px`

Comment: Yes I have this exact problem and am also interested in a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add this to your stylesheet it should fix your problem:

```
.ui-dialog { margin:0 auto; }
```

Comment: It worked! Why is this omitted from the CSS? Has a bug already been reported?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use or like jQuery UI in comparison to jQuery Tools...  so the onus of reporting is on you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the smoothness theme for 1.8.9 two nights ago and had the same issue. Margin css solution works for me. I load additional style rules after the theme to override some of the theme settings. Don't know why it is missing though...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by binding the `window` `resize` event.

```
var $dialog = $("#dialog");
$dialog.dialog();

$(window).resize(function(e){
    var $w = $(this),
        $d = $dialog.parent(),
        x = $w.width()/2-($d.width()/2),
        y = $w.height()/2-($d.height()/2);
    $dialog.dialog('option', 'position', [x, y]);
});
```

Check this [**demo on jSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/cT4CU/5/).

Answer (score 0):

The latest jquery-ui download has this style for the dialog

```
.ui-dialog 
{ 
   position: absolute; 
   padding: .2em; 
   width: 300px; 
   overflow: hidden; 
}
```

That definitely works in chrome. I think the older version had `position: relative` so that might be your problem

Comment: I am using the latest version - 1.8.9 Chrome is just refusing to center the dialog :(

Comment: @crimson yes mVchr's solution works perfectly, but when I changed my CSS to use absolute positioning that also fixed it. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is having this issue on IE but not on Chrome or FF, try adding some doctype to the page. This worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```